# What is causing "not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver" every time I run the "InputStream input = rs.getBinaryStream("FileName");" line?

Tags: java, sqlite, blob

I was trying to use query blob data from sqlite database, here is my full code

```
package team2.entity;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import team2.controller.sqliteCon;

public class LectureFiles {
    private String code;
    private static String fileName;

public LectureFiles(String code, String fileName){
    this.code = code;
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}

public void setFileName(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

private static LectureFiles convertToLectFiles(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException{
    LectureFiles LF;
    String code = rs.getString("Code");
    String fileName = rs.getString("FileName");
    LF = new LectureFiles(code, fileName);
    return LF;
}

/**
 * Read the file and returns the byte array
 * @param file
 * @return the bytes of the file
 */

private static byte[] readFile(String file){
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = null;
    try {
        File f = new File(file);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        for(int len = 0; (fis.read(buffer))!=-1;){
            bos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bos != null ? bos.toByteArray(): null;
}

public static boolean updateLectFiles(LectureFiles LF){
    // declare local variables
    boolean success = false;
    sqliteCon con = new sqliteCon();
    PreparedStatement pstmt;
    String dbQuery;
    // step 1 - establish connection to database
    con.getConnection();
    // step 2 - declare the SQL statement
    dbQuery = "INSERT INTO LectureFiles (code, filename) VALUES(?, ?)";
    // step 3 - to insert record using executeUpdate method
    pstmt = con.getPreparedStatement(dbQuery);
    try {
        pstmt.setString(1, LF.getCode());
        pstmt.setBytes(2, readFile(fileName));
        if(pstmt.executeUpdate()==1){
            success = true;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // step 4 - close connection
    con.terminate();
    return success;
}

public static void retrieveLectFilesByCode(LectureFiles LF){
    // declare local variables
    //ArrayList<LectureFiles> LFlist = new ArrayList<LectureFiles>();
    sqliteCon con = new sqliteCon();
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    String dbQuery;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    // step 1 - connect to database
    con.getConnection();
    // step 2 - declare the SQL statement
    dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM LectureFiles WHERE Code = ?";
    pstmt = con.getPreparedStatement(dbQuery);

    //step 3 - execute query and write binary stream into file
    try {
        pstmt.setString(1, LF.getCode());
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        File file = new File(fileName);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

        System.out.println("Writing BLOB to file " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        while(rs.next()){
            InputStream input = rs.getBinaryStream("FileName");// this is where the error is
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while(input.read(buffer) > 0){
                fos.write(buffer);
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (pstmt != null) {
                pstmt.close();
            }
            if (con != null) {
                con.terminate();
            }
            if (fos != null) {
                fos.close();
            }

        } catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}



public static void main(String [] args){
    /*LectureFiles LF = new LectureFiles("Code", "C:\\Users\\Thura_98\\Desktop\\OOAD Images\\Lecture128.png");
    updateLectFiles(LF);*/
    LectureFiles LF2 = new LectureFiles("Code", "C:\\Users\\Thura_98\\Desktop\\OOAD Images\\Lecture128_Blob.png");
    retrieveLectFilesByCode(LF2);
}
```

}

I was able to successfully save a file as a blob into database but I was unable to query blob data from sqlite database. Everytime the compiler runs the InputStream input = rs.getBinaryStream("FileName");" line, it always gives the  "not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver". So, it creates the file but does not have the contents. By the way, I used these sources to help me out
http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/jdbc-read-write-blob/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqHyCZkon34&t=250s
Any form of help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Isn't the message "not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver" sufficient enough?

Comment: Did you try `getBytes()`  or `getBlob()`? Maybe _those_ methods are implemented.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I used getBytes in the updateLectFiles method

Comment: Then why don't you use it in `retrieveLectFilesByCode` as well?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried but it gives the java.io.FileNotFoundException error

Comment: Hey @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks alot for the help, it's working now, really appreciate it